# How to passback result to Activity from Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am working on code where I need to pass result achieved from Fragment back to Activity class and finish the Activity .

I am referring to link : https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#separate

In this there needs to be

> MyLifecycleObserver

from Fragment to Activity .

But how can I add

> ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult

to MyLifecycleObserver and passback the result in Activity class

Comment: Well, can't you just handle the result in the fragment and cast the activity in which the fragment is placed so that you would just call the function of the activity with the result?

Comment: You're looking at APIs for talking Activity to Activity, not Fragment to Activity. Have you read the [guide to communicating with fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate) which specifically talks about communicating between a Fragment and it's activity?